# What's up with OpenJump?

Tags: references, openjump

[OpenJump](http://www.openjump.org) is a nice GIS, very functional, with many updates and has a beautiful rendering but it's not very popular, and you don't see it around in discussions, in osgeo comunity, etc.

So, what's up with OpenJump i.e. what's its development path?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OpenJUMP is developed by a small group of volunteers, of which I am one. The volunteers release the code through the Jump Pilot Project on SourceForge. The pace of development is definitely slow, as there is no paid development on the program. However, there is good cooperation and coordination amoing the small group of core programmers and a supportive user community.

One of these days I'd like to see OpenJUMP become an OSGeo Project, but that is mostly a question of resources, which we don't have right now.

Answer (score 5):

It is being developed...

Nightly Builds
http://jump-pilot.sourceforge.net/download/nightlybuild/
(21st March 2011)

Releases are not so regular but it's better to release stable software rather than buggy software.

Road is highlighting areas
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jump-pilot/index.php?title=OpenJUMP_Roadmap

Answer (score 5):

3 years later, we are still alive and kicking. just released OpenJUMP 1.8.0 . By the way, OJ runs on Windows, Linux, MacOSX.

We have a [website](http://www.openjump.org/) and a [wiki](http://ojwiki.soldin.de/) to help users out:

- snapshots, for users to try out the latest development
- mailing lists/bug trackers for issues
- search the wiki if you want to know more.